# ¿Que tengo mal en este flowchart?

Tags: python

Tengo este flowchart y necesito traducción en python. He llegado a este codigo pero me marca conforme no sería correcto y la verdad que no entiendo el por que.

```
cad=input('Introdueix una cadena de caracters')
i=0
car=''

for i in range (len(cad)):
    if (i<=len(cad)/2):
        c=cad[i]
        cad[i]=cad[len(cad)-i]
        cad[i+1]=c
        c=cad[i]
        
        if(car>cad[i]):
            car=cad[i]
        else:
            if(car>cad[len(cad-i)]): car=cad[len(cad)-i]
    else:
        print(cad,car)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Quieres decir que no se ve o que con mi cogido no lo consigue leer? Muchas gracias

Comment: Quizás el corrector esperaba que usaras un `while` en vez de un `for`. El resto de detalles no se leen bien en el diagrama, como para verificar que estés realizando las comparaciones y asignaciones correctas.

Comment: Ya he corregido el error y diria que ahora se puede visualizar de forma correcta el diagrama.

Answer (score 0):

No estoy muy seguro de entender el diagrama de flujo, pero tienes dos bucles en tu código, sin embargo, en el diagrama de flujo sólo aparece uno.

```py
cad=input('Introdueix una cadena de caracters')
i=0
car=''

for i in range(len(cad)/2):
    c=cad[i]
    cad[i]=cad[len(cad)-i]
    cad[i+1]=c
    c=cad[i]
        
    if(car>cad[i]):
        car=cad[i]
    else:
        if(car>cad[len(cad-i)]): car=cad[len(cad)-i]

print(cad,car)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, creo que ese era uno de los errores que tenía.

Comment: Perfecto. Si has solucionado el problema, por favor marca la respuesta como correcta. Si no es así, actualiza tu problema con el error que aún quede por resolver.